# Does mod_proxy support HTML5 Server Side Events / EventSource?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-proxy, html5

I am stuck with apache2.  I've read that mod_proxy doesn't support websockets.  Does it support EventSource?

https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=47485

Answer (score 0):

`EventSource` should be fine with mod_proxy, since `EventSource` is less complex in communications and runs on your Application layer (HTML), as long as you enable persistent connections (Keep Alives).

I've found a fair bit of issues with WebSockets over proxies, particularly over large corporate networks, which employ proxy routers that don't allow persistent connections, so you might find this may also have an impact for any live communication.   A [`Comet`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)) fallback (then AJAX polling) might be a good backup plan just in case.

If you're looking for a way to push live server events and only need the one-way communication, you should check out [Pusher](https://pusher.com) or some sort of polyfill for backward support.  :)

Hope that helps.